# How to execute pyc file without unicode errors

Tags: python, unicode

I have a "insval.py" file, when i'm importing it on IDE - has been created a "insval.pyc".

Then, when i'm trying run a pyc file i'm occur this errors:

1)

```
exec(open(r'D:\BPO Helper\firms\insval\insval.pyc').read())
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 391: character maps to <undefined>
```

2)

```
exec(open(r'D:\BPO Helper\firms\insval\insval.pyc', encoding='ansi').read())
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

3)

```
exec(open(r'D:\BPO Helper\firms\insval\insval.pyc', encoding='cp1251').read())
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 391: character maps to <undefined>
```

4)

```
exec(open(r'D:\BPO Helper\firms\insval\insval.pyc', encoding='utf-8').read())
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\codecs.py", line 321, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 12: invalid continuation byte
```

How i can avoid that ?

Comment: Why are you trying to read a `.pyc` file? You can if you open it in binary mode (i.e. `open("your_file.pyc", "rb")`) but what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm need to run script from this file. One module work like a launcher, in other - script for work. That's why i'm try to use a exec command and pyc file to prevent a fast reverse engineering.

Answer (score 1):

`*.pyc` files are not text files so you need to open them in binary mode, otherwise Python will try to decode them to ascii/utf-8 and fail.

```
pyc_file = r"D:\BPO Helper\firms\insval\insval.pyc"
with open(pyc_file, "rb") as pyc:
    exec(pyc.read())
```

But unless you have the actual source in a file weirdly named `*.pyc` this will not work. You cannot execute compiled code this way, however you can import it:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"D:\BPO Helper\firms\insval")
import insval
```

But I still don't get why would you want to do this. Just don't compile your Python files (Python will do it for you in the back) and load them the normal way.

**UPDATE** - If you really insist on going down this `.pyc` road, you can ultimately load your `.pyc` files, unmarshal them, extract the code object(s) and then have it run by `exec()`.

```
# here be dragons, you've been warned
import marshal

pyc_file = r"D:\BPO Helper\firms\insval\insval.pyc"
with open(pyc_file, "rb") as pyc:
    pyc.seek(8)  # skip the header, for Python v3.3+ pyc's use 12 bytes instead 
    code = marshal.load(pyc)  # unmarshal the pyc into code object(s)
    exec(code)  # with some luck, this will work
```

This is way too fragile to be used in any sort of a production code but again, if you insist...

Comment: From yours example i occur this error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\BPO Helper\bpo_launcher.py", line 63, in <module>
        exec(pyc.read())
    ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Comment: I'm trying use a pyc files 'cause wanna hide my code from end user and prevent fast reverse engineering. Why using exec instead import: in bpo_launcher.py (user select company for work) -> exec(open(insval.py).read()) - > insval.py read data from pdf and works with them. -> (if user need read data from new pdf) -> using exec comand to run itself and works with data

Comment: First of all, run your `.pyc` files through [`uncompyle6`](https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6/) or [`pycdc`](https://github.com/zrax/pycdc) just to see how much code you're 'hiding' and how much you're preventing fast reverse engineering (hint: not much). Second, Python's `exec()` clearly states that it can execute only strings containing Python source or code objects, both of which `.pyc` files are not. You can unmarshal the `.pyc` file (I'll add an example above) but that road will eventually bring you up to a brick wall and you'll have to go back and rethink your idea.

Comment: Seems yes, need to find other way to hide code. Ty for help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  this `D:\BPO Helper\firms\insval\insval.pyc'`,
try `D:\\BPO Helper\\firms\\insval\\insval.pyc'`,

Comment: They are equal o_0

Comment: Double this '\'

Comment: This don't helps. Was trying it :)

Comment: Did you make changes on every path ?

Comment: @RonBurgundy - you don't need double quotes when you use _raw_ strings. Besides, his error has nothing to do with file not found.